# How i can use WHERE command when i already use join in my command

Tags: php, sql

Code Below

```
<?php $sql = "SELECT tblstudents.FullName,tblbooks.BookName,tblbooks.ISBNNumber,tblissuedbookdetails.IssuesDate,tblissuedbookdetails.ReturnDate,tblissuedbookdetails.id as rid from  tblissuedbookdetails join tblstudents on tblstudents.StudentId=tblissuedbookdetails.StudentId join tblbooks on tblbooks.id=tblissuedbookdetails.BookId order by tblissuedbookdetails.id desc";
$query = $dbh -> prepare($sql);
$query->execute();
```

I want to add WHERE so i can show only the specific data
I already try add WHERE in the end like this

```
<?php $sql = "SELECT tblstudents.FullName,tblbooks.BookName,tblbooks.ISBNNumber,tblissuedbookdetails.IssuesDate,tblissuedbookdetails.ReturnDate,tblissuedbookdetails.id as rid from  tblissuedbookdetails join tblstudents on tblstudents.StudentId=tblissuedbookdetails.StudentId join tblbooks on tblbooks.id=tblissuedbookdetails.BookId order by tblissuedbookdetails.id desc WHERE RetrunedStatus = 1";
```

And this is my database

[image: database]

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this?

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there. You got the order of the `ORDER BY` and `WHERE` clauses wrong. Move `ORDER BY` after your `WHERE` statement like this:

```
SELECT tblstudents.FullName,tblbooks.BookName,tblbooks.ISBNNumber,tblissuedbookdetails.IssuesDate,tblissuedbookdetails.ReturnDate,tblissuedbookdetails.id as rid from  tblissuedbookdetails join tblstudents on tblstudents.StudentId=tblissuedbookdetails.StudentId join tblbooks on tblbooks.id=tblissuedbookdetails.BookId WHERE RetrunedStatus = 1 order by tblissuedbookdetails.id desc
```

From your schema I can see that your column name is `RetrunStatus`, where in your query you wrote 'RetrunedStatus'. These should be consistent, and may be renamed to 'ReturnStatus' to fix the typo.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest specifying which join you're willing to perform, also rearrange places of `ORDER BY` and `WHERE` clause and typo of `RetrunStatus` as mentioned by Ro.

SQL Example -

```
SELECT tblstudents.FullName,tblbooks.BookName,tblbooks.ISBNNumber,tblissuedbookdetails.IssuesDate,tblissuedbookdetails.ReturnDate,tblissuedbookdetails.id as rid from  tblissuedbookdetails inner join tblstudents on tblstudents.StudentId=tblissuedbookdetails.StudentId inner join tblbooks on tblbooks.id=tblissuedbookdetails.BookId WHERE tblissuedbookdetails.RetrunStatus = 1 order by tblissuedbookdetails.id desc";
```